# Is there a Visual Studio or Resharper plugin that shows broken HtmlHelpers?

Tags: visual-studio

I am refactoring several large controllers into individual controllers for readablity and for the Single Responsability Principle.

Is there a plugin/extension for Visual Studio (or ReSharper) that shows me which views have broken HtmlHelpers in them?